# how to seperate an array with two different id's using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv, explode

how to extract an array with to different id's notice the css_id click image for more sample

```
[0] => Array(
        [cses_id] => 54
        [ccc_id] => 1157
        [csh_id] => 206
        [css_id] => 441,442
        [sai_id] => 12213

    )

expedted output below
*********************************************
[0] => Array(
        [cses_id] => 54
        [ccc_id] => 1157
        [csh_id] => 206
        [css_id] => 441
        [sai_id] => 12213

    )

[1] => Array(
        [cses_id] => 54
        [ccc_id] => 1157
        [csh_id] => 206
        [css_id] => 442
        [sai_id] => 12213

    )
```

[click here for another sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWWbk.jpg)

Comment: explode on comma?

Comment: is this from your db? thats why never save data like this, keep them on separate rows

Comment: sorry i will edit it

Comment: @yes ghost it is from db is there a way to manipulate this in array?

Comment: @rtfm array come from DB

Comment: super, still explode on the comma, create new array

Comment: @rtfm do you have script for this?

Comment: https://ideone.com/HGwNpk

Comment: How might this input vary? Will there only be one element with comma separated values? might there be more? How should that look?  If two columns contain multiple values, do you want "columns" of data to "stay together"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task can be performed many ways. This is just one way that will work for your sample input array.  See inline comments for explanation.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/f7Pkm))

```
$array=['cses_id'=>'54','ccc_id'=>'1157','csh_id'=>'206','css_id'=>'441,442','sai_id'=>'12213'];

$count=0;

// convert each comma-separated value to an array of values & store the max comma count
$multi=array_map(function($v)use(&$count){$count=max($count,substr_count($v,',')); return explode(',',$v);},$array);
++$count;  // increment to know how many "columns" of values exist
for($col=0; $col<$count; ++$col){
    $temp=[];
    foreach($multi as $key=>&$val){
        $temp[$key]=(sizeof($val)>1?array_shift($val):current($val));  // take off the front element until only one is left (and repeat the use of final value)
    }
    $result[]=$temp;  // store this batch of columnar data
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'cses_id' => '54',
    'ccc_id' => '1157',
    'csh_id' => '206',
    'css_id' => '441',
    'sai_id' => '12213',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'cses_id' => '54',
    'ccc_id' => '1157',
    'csh_id' => '206',
    'css_id' => '442',
    'sai_id' => '12213',
  ),
)
```

---

Here's another way to achieve the same result: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/2YDPI))

```
$array=['cses_id'=>'54','ccc_id'=>'1157','csh_id'=>'206','css_id'=>'441,442','sai_id'=>'12213'];
do {
    $stop=true;                      // default to stop after each iteration
    $temp=[];                        // clear the $temp variable
    foreach($array as $key=>&$val){  // iterate associate array, modify $val by reference
        $parts=explode(',',$val,2);  // break the value on the first comma only
        $temp[$key]=$parts[0];       // associatively store first value to the temp array
        if(sizeof($parts)>1){        // if there was a comma this iteration...
            $stop=false;             // tell the loop to do another iteration
            $val=$parts[1];          // modify $array by overwriting $val with the remaining comma-separated value
        }
    }
    $result[]=$temp;                 // this this iteration's temporary array in the result array
} while(!$stop);                     // iterate while there are any commas still in the any of the elements

var_export($result);                 // print to screen
```

Comment: @christophercaburog If this doesn't work for your actual project data, you will need to update your question with more accurate sample data and the expected output.

Comment: @christopher fyi, I've just added an alternative method for you.